# Java NIO Selector dosen't wakeUp

Tags: java, nio

Got some questions about java non nonblocking socket.

Unplug the client's LAN cable and close the client's SocketChannel if there is no heartbeat message for 5 seconds in Timer thread.

```java
private void startSendHeartBeatMessage() {
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (connections.size() != 0) {
                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                Iterator<MessageClient> iterator = connections.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    MessageClient client = iterator.next();
                    if (client.isClientAlive(now)) {
                        // got a heartbeat 5 seconds ago
                        client.setData("heartbeat".getBytes());
                        SelectionKey key = client.getSocketChannel().keyFor(selector);
                        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE); // send heartbeat to client 
                    } else {
                        // remove client and close socketChannel
                        log.error("time out");
                        client.getSocketChannel().close();
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
            selector.wakeup();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

Of course, channel close is called because the lan cable is unplugged.

```java
private void startServer() {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (selector.select(1000) > 0) { // wait for event
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                    while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                        SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                        keyIterator.remove();
                        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                            accept(key);
                        } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                            MessageClient client = (MessageClient) key.attachment();
                            client.receive(key, selector);
                        } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                            MessageClient client = (MessageClient) key.attachment();
                            client.send(key, selector);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            stopServer();
        }
    });
    startSendHeartBeatMessage();
}
```

After client's `socketChannel` closed
Timer's `selector.wakeup()` and `selector.select(1000)` is not wakeup blocking and didn't catch any event in `SelectionKey`
But the client prints out that the connection and message transmission were successful.

As a result of checking, `KQueueSelectorImpl` `wakeup()` is called and `interruptTriggered` always `true` when the lan plug was unplugged and the socketChannel was closed.

```java
/**
 * KQueue based Selector implementation for macOS
 */
class KQueueSelectorImpl extends SelectorImpl {
    public Selector wakeup() {
        synchronized (interruptLock) {
            if (!interruptTriggered) {
                try {
                    IOUtil.write1(fd1, (byte)0);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    throw new InternalError(ioe);
                }
                interruptTriggered = true;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Not unplugging the LAN cable
Closing the client via cntr + c allows reconnection very normally.

I really don't know the internal working structure of NIO. Please help me

The execution environment runs on MacBook's and Spring Boot 2.

Thanks for reading.